# Is it possible to make a static library from a header only file through visual studio?

Tags: c++

By following some tutorials, I was successfully able to make a static library through visual studio , but it only works if there is a corresponding .cpp file for the .h file. Take these two files for example

.h

```
void print();
```

.cpp

```
void print()
{
    std::cout << "printing from lib";
}
```

I went I to

`project->properties->configuration properties->configuration type`

and set the configuration type to static library. When I build this, it makes the required .lib files and stores it in the debug folder. It also outputs this to the output console.

```
1>engine.vcxproj -> C:\Users\me\source\repos\game\Debug\engine.lib
```

But now if I delete the .cpp file and change the .h file to

```
void print()
{
     std::cout << "printing from lib";
}
```

and then try to build, it says build successful, but It does not create any .lib files. It also does not output

```
 `1>engine.vcxproj -> C:\Users\me\source\repos\game\Debug\engine.lib`
```

Comment: AFAIK, a static library must contain at least one translation unit. A header doesn't provide a translation unit but is intended to be `#include`d in one. So, a header-only "library" is just a header (or a set of headers) which can be used elsewhere but it (they) cannot be linked as static library (nor is this necessary).

Comment: You don't need a .lib file, since the .h can be included in any downstream project .

Comment: Your change to the header would also result in multiple definition errors. I mean if the header was used in more than 1 cpp file.

Comment: When I want to expose a header-only library (static or dynamic) as a separate Visual Studio project, I use the trick of a dummy symbol in a dummy `.cc` file just to have something to make the linker happy. (I've seen this in other projects also.)

Comment: @drescherjm that's easy to fix by putting `inline` in front of the function.  Even if the linker finds multiple copies it will consistently pick one without complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the compiler to run on a header file, but for your own sanity and those of future maintenance developers, just put a `.cpp` file with the single line

```
#include "library.h"
```

Note that libraries distributed in header files usually do so because of templates and will not make a useful static library.